# Preventing SharePoint from converting email addresses to mailto links

Tags: wss-3.0, email

I have a WSS 3.0 SharePoint site that is automatically displaying email addresses as mailto link.  Ideally I want to prevent this from happening, this is a customised site and we will be forcing users to use the discussion area to send emails.

Is there anyway to turn this facility off? It appears to be site specific i.e. I can enter an email address in any text field and it displays as converted to a mailto link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I've basically cheated by doing a jQuery update to the page instead:-

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href^=mailto:]").each(function(){  
        var sEmailAddress = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith(sEmailAddress);
    });
});
```

If anyone does know if the mailto link conversion can be disabled I'd be interested to know, but the work around does the business for now.