# How to turn off the function that converts single line of text into mailto: link

Tags: 2010, list, hyperlink

Does anybody know how to turn off automatic text conversion into mailto: links inside basic single line of text fields? It is confusing a little bit. Our customers stores server configurations in lists with various columns like number of processors, HDD type or CPU speed and if they insert something like this: E7-4870@2.40GHz, some processes in the background convert it into active mailto: link. I know, we can create items without both @. symbols, but I would rather disable it. Thanks

[image]

Comment: fwiw - I just verified that it is SharePoint that it doing this as the mailto: is in the original html that is being sent by SharePoint.  It is not being done in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

someone had a similar issue to you:

their solution was to use jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href^=mailto:]").each(function(){  
        var sEmailAddress = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith(sEmailAddress);
    });
});
```

[Preventing SharePoint from converting email addresses to mailto links](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2843/preventing-sharepoint-from-converting-email-addresses-to-mailto-links)

Comment: I'm afraid, that this solution will not be accepted here but thank you, its worth to try

Answer (score 4):

I am not seeing any way to turn this off but I discovered that if you create a new Calculated field and simply set that field equal to the field giving you trouble that it does not add the mailto link on views.  It would at least be a workaround

Comment: This unfortunately doesnt work for multi-line fields as those cant be used in formulas :(

Answer (score 3):

Add spaces?

This [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659608/how-to-prevent-converting-ab-to-a-mailto-link-in-contenteditable-div-in-ie) post might help. I think it's a browser thing and not Sharepoint doing that.

Comment: That's what I need, fully supported (here) is IE anyway. But, I think turning this automatic URL detection off means deactivate links everywhere (including site pages). Could be turned off for selected pages (lists) only? (I'm sorry, I'm not a programmer)

Comment: There might be another issue caused by browser, but SP for sure does the replacement - it is biting me wheni try to use the plain text description in the title attribute.