# Remove a HyperLink in a list field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, hyperlink

I have a field in my share point view where I have an email address.  The email address is displayed as a hyperlink.

I have copied the field in and prior to the copy I removed the hyperlink but it keeps defaulting to the hyperlink.

How do I remove the hyperlink?

Comment: Please take a look at the [related question here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62868/how-to-turn-off-the-function-that-converts-single-line-of-text-into-mailto-link)

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem in the list view can be done simply and without opening SPD:

1. Make sure the value you want to display for the lookup column is also selected as one of the "also show these columns" choices for that lookup (yes, you can include the most helpful column as both the value for 'In this column' as well as tick it in the additional fields list)
2. (Optional) Edit the display name of the new additional column if you like.
3. Edit the list view and swap the main lookup column for the additional column.