# Emails change to HTML code when field is edited in custom list

Tags: custom-list

One of my clients came to me with an issue. Their custom list has a single line of text field where they contact information for their incoming clients. They take either a phone number or an email address, which is fine. But when they edit the field for whatever reason, the email addresses change from a clickable link to the HTML a href mailto link.

I think a reasonable solution to this would be to turn off clickable links for the custom list, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email addresses and URLS converting to links is a SharePoint default behavior. When you edit the list view in Quick edit mode sometimes if you try to edit email it will show complete HTML `mailto` tag versus plain text. The user should correct before they do save.

To disable the links and convert back to plain text there are couple of ways

1. Modifying the XSL code the list view
2. Instead of a single line of text using Multiple line text (Enhance rich text).
3. Add a JavaScirpt to the list view page which converts `mailto` tags to plain text.

Refer below links for examples

1. [Using XSLT or multiple line text](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9dfc0011-78f8-4568-b150-632278b97050/list-view-formatting-email-address-with-hyperlink?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)
2. [Using JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2843/preventing-sharepoint-from-converting-email-addresses-to-mailto-links)

Comment: I will look into using the multiple lines of text for future iterations of the custom list, but in the mean time, it looks like that JavaScript will do the job. Where would I plug it in?

Comment: You need to add Script Editor web part on the list view page and add your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is some web browser option or extension that does this, not SharePoint. I could be wrong though.

Try doing it using another browser or disabling all toolbars and extensions - does it still do it?